# How to use parallelism in cython

Tags: python, c++, parallel-processing, openmp, cython

I'm trying to apply parallelism to the following algorithm. This should be easily parallelizable, as the calculations are independent for the first three dimensions `(b, i, j)`.

```
def nb_forward(np.ndarray[FLOAT64, ndim=4] inputv, np.ndarray[FLOAT64, ndim=4] kernels, np.ndarray[FLOAT64, ndim=1] bias, tuple stride):
    cdef unsigned int kernel_size0 = kernels.shape[1], kernel_size1 = kernels.shape[2], \
    stride0 = stride[0], stride1 = stride[1], \
    num_dim = kernels.shape[0], \
    num_filters = kernels.shape[3], \
    batch_size = inputv.shape[0]

    cdef unsigned int out_size0 = (inputv.shape[1] - kernel_size0) / stride0 + 1, \
    out_size1 = (inputv.shape[2] - kernel_size1) / stride1 + 1

    cdef double[:, :, :, :] out = np.empty(shape=[batch_size, out_size0, out_size1, num_filters], dtype=np.float64)

    cdef unsigned int b, i, j, m, kw, kh, n
    cdef unsigned int iin, jin
    cdef double acc

    with nogil, parallel():
        for b in prange(batch_size):
            for i in range(out_size0):
                for j in range(out_size1):
                    iin = i*stride0
                    jin = j*stride1

                    for n in range(num_filters):
                        acc = 0.
                        for kw in range(kernel_size0):
                            for kh in range(kernel_size1):
                                for m in range(num_dim):
                                    acc += inputv[b, iin + kw, jin + kh, m] * kernels[m, kw, kh, n]
                        out[b, i, j, n] = acc + bias[n]
    return out

Error:
Cannot read reduction variable in loop body
```

Initially I tried to parallelize only at the level of `b`, since parallelizing at level `b`, `i, j` is at the pixel level and I do not know if it is worth generating as many threads. But I have not succeeded.

I tried to use a temporary array `out_batch`, but being a `numpy` array, it is giving me a lot of problems and

```
Error: malloc problems
```

I have also tried instead of using `numpy` array using `double arrays` (`double [:,:,:]`) but it gives:

```
Error: Memoryview slices can only be shared in parallel sections
```

Does anyone have an idea? Is there any way to apply **nogil** at the level of `b`, `i`, `j` (or only `b`) and then compact the data?

Comment: Isn't there any library that can help you here? E.g. [one of these](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing)?

Comment: It kind of looks like this might be Cython getting confused about the role of `acc` loop. I wonder if it might work better if you could put most of the loop body into a `cdef` function call (eg `out[b,i,j,:] = f(some parameters)`)

Comment: I have tried using cython directly to gain performance. The problem is that the algorithm is used in a neural network project, it is one of the bottlenecks and I need to optimize it to the maximum without using deep learning libraries. I think that prange uses Openmp internally.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the variable `acc` is shared between all threads and thus it can come to raise conditions - Cython rightly doesn't let this code to compile.

The variable `acc` shouldn't be shared between the threads, but be private to a thread. However, to my limited knowledge, there is no way to do it with cython yet (not sure what happened with this [proposal](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-prange#explicit-thread-local-variables)).

A usual workaround is to allocate a large enough working array `tmp` and to accumulate the value for i-th thread in `tmp[i]`. Often enough (but not always) already presented arrays can be used for this purpose, so also in your case - by replacing `acc` through `out[b,i,j,n]`:

```
for n in range(num_filters):
    out[b, i, j, n] = 0.
    for kw in range(kernel_size0):
        for kh in range(kernel_size1):
            for m in range(num_dim):
                out[b, i, j, n] += inputv[b, iin + kw, jin + kh, m] * kernels[m, kw, kh, n]
    out[b, i, j, n] += bias[n]
```